# Does there exist two linearly independent functions $u$ in $\mathbb{R}^{2}$ satsfying $\bar{\partial}^{2}u(x,y) + A(x,y)u(x,y) = 0$?

Tags: complex-analysis, ordinary-differential-equations, partial-differential-equations, complex-geometry, riemann-surfaces

Does there exist two linearly independent functions $u$ in $\mathbb{R}^{2}$ satsfying
$$\frac{\partial^{2}}{\partial \bar{z}^{2}}u(x,y) + A(x,y)u(x,y) = 0$$
where $A\in C^{\infty}(\mathbb{R}^{2})$?

We define

$$\frac{\partial}{\partial\bar{z}}u(x,y) ={\frac {1}{2}}\left({\frac {\partial }{\partial x}u(x,y)} + i{\frac {\partial }{\partial y}}u(x,y)\right).$$

We know that if $A$ is a antiholomorphic function, then our equation has two independent antiholomorphic solutions $u$.

Comment: I think this is interesting but the question could use some polishing up. Can you add the definition of Wirtinger's derivative? It is nice to have it on the same page.

Comment: Wait a minute. If $u$ is holomorphic then $\partial_{\overline z}u=0$. Then how can there be a holomorphic solution to $(\partial_{\overline z})^2 u+ Au=0$, unless $A=0$?

Comment: Sorry, it's antiholomorphic. We can represent antiholomorphic coefficient  as a series and as we want antiholomorphic function so we can write it as a series in $\bar{z}$.

Answer (score 2):

It seems to me that this fails already in your example with $A=0$. All entire functions solve $$(\partial_\overline z)^2u=0, $$ and certainly that is not a 2-dimensional space.

**EDIT**. It is now clear that you want **at least** two independent solutions. This may be true and it is not disproved by this answer. This (trivial) answer proves that there may be **more** than two independent solutions.

Comment: $z$ and $\bar{z}$ are two independent solutions for this equation.

Comment: Ok, so you want **at least** two independent solutions, not **exactly** two. Is that right?

Comment: Yes, You are right.